# I am having problems with compareTo

Tags: java, methods, compareto

Well, I need to make a project where I have two interfaces and they are both used in two unrelated classes. I managed to get everything else to work out properly except for the compareTo method. The two classes I have made are Car and Horse. What I am trying to do is compare the milesGoal from Horse to the one in Car and return either a 1, 0, or -1.

However when I try doing this I get the error "double could not be dereferenced"

I have been stuck on this for a while trying to find different ways to approach this part of the code. I tried using compareTo in the tester class instead of making a method but I got the same error and I am required to make it into a method.

This is the Horse Class:

```
public class Horse implements milesInterface , kilometersInterface{
private double currentMile;
private double currentKilo;
private double milesGoal;
private double kilosGoal;
private String horseBreed;

// CONSTRUCTORS
public Horse(){
    currentMile = 0;
    currentKilo = 0;
    milesGoal = 0;
    kilosGoal = 0;
    horseBreed = "Unspecified";
}
public Horse(double cm, double ck, double mg, double kg, String hb){
    currentMile = cm;
    currentKilo = ck;
    milesGoal = mg;
    kilosGoal = kg;
    horseBreed = hb;
}

// MILE METHODS
public double remainingMiles(){ // Finds the remaining miles
    return milesGoal-currentMile;
}
public void halfMile(){ // Divides the desired goal halfway (Miles)
    milesGoal = milesGoal/2;
} 
public void setMileGoal(double newMile){ // Allows you to set a new goal
    milesGoal = newMile;
}
public double getMileGoal(){
    return milesGoal;
}

// KILOMETER METHODS
public double remainingKilos(){ // Finds the remaining Kilos
return kilosGoal-currentKilo;
}
public void halfKilo(){ // Divides the desire goal halfway (Kilos)
    kilosGoal = kilosGoal/2;
}
public void setKiloGoal(){ // Allows you to set a new goal
    kilosGoal = milesGoal*1.6;
}
public void setCurrentKilo(){ // Allows you to set the current Kilo
    currentKilo = currentMile * 1.6;
}

// UNIQUE METHODS
public double getMilesStatus(){
    return currentMile;
}
public double getKilosStatus(){
    return currentKilo;
}
public String getHorseBreed(){
    return horseBreed;
}
public void convertToKilos(){ // Converts current miles to kilometers
    double kilos = currentMile * 1.6;
    System.out.println("The current miles to kilometers is: " + kilos + "km.");
}
public void convertToMiles(){ // Converts current kilometers to miles
    double miles = currentKilo * .6;
    System.out.println("The current kilometers to miles is: " + miles + "m.");
}
public void milesPerHour(double hours){ // Calculates the mph to the goal by a time
double answer = milesGoal / hours;
System.out.println("The mph needed to reach the desination in " + hours + " hours: " + answer);
}
 public void kilosPerHour(double hours){ // Calculates the kmph to the goal by a time
double answer = kilosGoal / hours;
System.out.println("The kilometers needed to reach the desination in " + hours + " hours: " + answer);
}
public int compareTo(Object Other){

    if(milesGoal > (Horse)milesGoal.Other)
        return 1;
    if(milesGoal < (Horse)milesGoal.Other)
        return 0;
        return -1;
    }
 }
```

The Car class is pretty much the same as the Horse one and I need to find a way to compare both of their milesGoal to see which one is greater. I tried multiple things but it doesn't seem to work

This is the interface I made:

```
abstract interface milesInterface{
public double remainingMiles();
public void halfMile();
public void setMileGoal(double newMile);
public int compareTo(Object Other);
}
abstract interface kilometersInterface{
public double remainingKilos();
public void halfKilo();
public void setCurrentKilo();
public int compareTo(Object Other);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are writting `attribute.object`. This is what fails. `Other.milesGoal` is a better option.

Another problema is with the casting. What you are doing is trying to cast `milesGoal.other` to `Horse` (you want to cast `milesGoal`)

You should use

```
       if (milesGoal > ((Horse) other).milesGoal)
```

Also, use proper capitalization (variables go in lowercase, clases/interfaces in uppercase) and setters and getters.

Additionally, you probably will want to cast to the interface so you can use the methods with other clases that implement it

```
       if (milesGoal > ((MilesInterface) other).milesGoal)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not getting no compile errors anymore I am going to try to finish everything now. Once again, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Another BIG THING. Unless you have a good reason to do so, do not define `compareTo` in your interfaces, make your class implement `java.util.Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `(Horse)milesGoal.Other` should be `((Horse) Other).milesGoal`.

I would suggest overloading `compareTo` with one method for comparing to `Horse`s and one method for comparing to `Car`s. Then your code looks like

```
public int compareTo(Horse horse){
    if(milesGoal > horse.milesGoal)
        return 1;
    if(milesGoal < horse.milesGoal)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

public int compareTo(Car car){
    if(milesGoal > car.milesGoal)
        return 1;
    if(milesGoal < car.milesGoal)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```